# Mysterious user from hell in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, php, third-party-module

I have installed magemonkey mailchimp extension via composer:

```
composer require ebizmarts/magento2-magemonkey
```

And then when I try run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I get an error:

```
[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                                                  
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 
'ifit_test_db'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have never created that user, and my site is running ok. When i try:

```
grep -r ifit_test_db
```

for that user, the command line is telling me:

```
app/etc/env.php:        'dbname' => 'ifit_test_db',
app/etc/env.php:        'username' => 'ifit_test_db',
```

When I open my app/etc/env.php file I dont see that dbname or username. I see the dbname and username that I set before. So where the hell is that user comming from?

Comment: Ok, someone at my office created new instance of the site with these credentials, and the rest is a history,,, i was in a wrong folder.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept.